# Bluetooth Serial Port on Raspberry Pi & something weird happened when using IDE and terminator to run python files

Tags: python, linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I am doing a project using the Bluetooth serial port. It is about the message communication between cellphones and the Rpi.

I typed **'sudo rfcomm watch hci0'** on the Terminator.

The code on Python is simple: only assign the port address ('/dev/rfcomm0') and readline().

At first, things went right until I disconnected and reconnected. It said, "**Cannot create Rfcomm TTY: Address already in use**". I guess it is because I didn't close the serial port, so I added 'ser.close()'. And then it worked. I ran it on Thonny (the IDE for Python on Rpi).

However, when I tried running the Python script on the Terminator, weird things happened. Initially, all things went right but when I disconnected the Bluetooth connection, it was stuck and if I tried reconnecting, it told me "**Cannot create Rfcomm TTY: Address already in use**" again.

So, what is the difference between running the script on IDE and on Terminator? It really confused me a lot because I am planning to make the script running automatically after rebooting.

Also, could someone tell me how to solve the error, "**Cannot create Rfcomm TTY: Address already in use**", in a better way?

Thank you!

I want to add more explanation.

When I use IDE to run the script:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPTiV.jpg)

It worked well when I disconnected and reconnected.

But when I use Terminator to run the script ("sudo Python3 xxxxxx.py"):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbo8Y.jpg)

It failed when I tried reconnecting. And the terminator got stuck and then ran abnormally when I disconnected and reconnected.

Comment: It is quite weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hciattach`, `hciconfig`, `hcitool`, `hcidump`, **`rfcomm`**, `sdptool`, `ciptool`, and `gatttool` were [deprecated by the BlueZ](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) project in 2017. If you are following a tutorial that uses them, there is a chance that it might be out of date.

The `Bluedot` library supports creating a server to communicate RFCOMM serial data. More details at:
https://bluedot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btcommapi.html#bluetoothserver

Comment: Thank you! If I use this Python library, do I still need to type "sudo rfcomm watch hci0" in the terminator? Or what I need to do is just using this library in my Python script. I don't quite understand this part. Thank you for explanation!

Comment: No you do not need to use `rfcomm`. Just what is in the Python script. There is some more information at: https://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2017/07/python-bluetooth-rfcomm-client-server.html  The client is your cellphone and not another RPi.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it. The client is my cellphone in the project but not RPi. Would you mind leaving me your email for more efficient communication? Thank you! If you want, I can leave mine.

Comment: My email is :qhaotian@umich.edu

Comment: That's not how Stackoverflow works. By keeping the discussion on here there is the opportunity for others to contribute and/or learn. If you are having problems with the Bluedot RFCOMM functionality, maybe ask a new question about it.

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Comment: Actually, my project will use the Android Bluetooth Serial Port Application to send messages. If I use the BlueDot, is that I will have to use the BlueDot ?

Comment: Bluedot implements the Bluetooth standard functionality of Serial Port Profile (SPP) as does Android Bluetooth Serial Port Applications. As they are both following the standard they should work together. There is also the following blog that shows how to do it with the standard Python Socket library.

Comment: So, does it mean that I can still use the Bluetooth SPP application that I used before? Or I have to use the BlueDot APP? It really matters because we want to develop some other functions. Sorry, I am a little bit awkward about the Bluetooth Protocol. Thanks for your patience.